# Display Dropbox images in Android app

Tags: android, image, webview, dropbox

i want to display images stored in my dropbox via a webview. when i try to load the url given from dropbox i only get the dropbox layout and the name of the image in the center , is there a way to do this?
If no , how can i display images stored in a cloud like Google Drive in my app?I cannot store them all in the app because of their size.Thanks in advance!

My code

```
 WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.catalogImageSlide); 
        webView.loadUrl(null);
        //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/"+getArguments().getString("img"));
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftd2x383ps8kbrd/046.jpg");
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Have you set the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest file ?

Comment: You might prefer to use `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ftd2x383ps8kbrd/046.jpg (just replace the domain name). That's a link directly to the image rather than a Dropbox page that previews the image.

Comment: Thanks!It's the solution to my problem, amazing how simple can be sometimes!Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

You can modify URL dropbox image before load in a WebView:

```
public static String modifyDropboxUrl(String originalUrl){
    String newUrl = originalUrl.replace("www.dropbox." ,"dl.dropboxusercontent.");
    //just for sure for case if www is missing in url string
    newUrl = newUrl.replace("dropbox.", "dl.dropboxusercontent.");
    return newUrl;
}
```

Link to original response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593584