# load image from url not working

Tags: android

I have this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri4xbjaz64kezsg/30.jpg in my code...but I can't download image from that link.. if i use link other then this link then i am able to download.
so what could problem with this link...plz help me

```
public class AndroidLoadImageFromURLActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;

    // Imageview to show
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Image url
    String image_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri4xbjaz64kezsg/30.jpg";

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
}
```

}

this is image loader class.....................

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
{
    stub_id = loader;
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(loader);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u;
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: try to remove 's' in https and try with http only.

Comment: @AndroidKiller i tried but that also not working..

Comment: Could you post the `ImageLoader` class?

Comment: @soulreaver i added image loader class..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download content of this link, you are actually downloading http web page and not image itself. 
This Dropbox webpage then display the image so you can see it in a browser but ImageLoader need direct link to image.

Direct link to the image would be

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ri4xbjaz64kezsg/30.jpg
```

and you can get it with replacing `www.dropbox` or just `dropbox` if the www is missing in url with `dl.dropboxusercontent`. Simple example help method:

```
public static String modifyDropboxUrl(String originalUrl)
{
    String newUrl = originalUrl.replace("www.dropbox." ,"dl.dropboxusercontent.");

    //just for sure for case if www is missing in url string
    newUrl = newUrl.replace("dropbox.", "dl.dropboxusercontent.");

    return newUrl;
}
```

Comment: Raska ..it's working thank's..but can you tell me how to convert my web page link in this link..

Comment: Raska k..thanks ..for this moment this code is working..and if you know how to implement with parsing image url from html page..plz help me..

Comment: thanks.again..but can u tell me that how to get this url.i mean how to   get from original url..

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the reason of the problem is that `ImageLoader` class doesn't support SSL while dropbox forces its clients to use it. Try using another class (with SSL support) for this task, maybe: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/188#issuecomment-14311274 .

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use library as the Universal Image Loader or AQuery ! that saves you so much time! Use this instead of your countless lines of code

```
AQuery aq = new Aquery(Activity.this);
 aq.id(R.id.imageview).image(url, true, true);
```

ive used aquery before it also handles caching! very very hassle free

Comment: ..i don't have idea how to use this library.

Comment: it is very simple bro...just download a fresh copy of AQuery in jar format. google for the file then paste the jar in your project's lib folder! refresh your project and you will be good to go!

Comment: and for coding by just adding  that given code in your answer will enough..or anything else

Comment: but a query not loading image from url in android pie @NirajAdhikari